# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space spark streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I've a spark streaming job. It operates in batches of 10 minutes. The driver machine is m4X4x (64GB) ec2 instance.

The job stalled after 18 hours. It crashes on the following exception. As I read the other posts it seems that the driver may have run out of memory. How can I check this? My pyspark config is as follows

Also, how do i check the memory in spark-ui ? I only see the 11 tasks nodes i have, not the driver.

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS='--master yarn --deploy-mode client

   --driver-memory 10g

   --executor-memory 10g

   --executor-cores 4

   --conf spark.driver.cores=5

   --packages "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2" 

   --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g

   --conf spark.shuffle.spill=true

   --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2048

   --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048

   --conf "spark.broadcast.blockSize=512M"

   --conf "spark.memory.storageFraction=0.5"

   --conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=1024"

   --conf "spark.default.parallelism=600"

   --conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=600"

   --driver-java-options -   Dlog4j.configuration=file:///usr/lib/spark/conf/log4j.properties pyspark-shell'

   [Stage 3507:>                                                     (0 + 0) / 600]Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$4.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$4.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.allocateNewChunkIfNeeded(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.write(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:75)
        at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flushBufferedData(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:205)
        at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.finish(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:235)
        at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.close(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:175)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.close(ObjectOutputStream.java:1828)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.close(ObjectOutputStream.java:742)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.close(JavaSerializer.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$blockifyObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1319)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1387)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1012)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage$4.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage$4.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:935)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:873)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1630)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
[Stage 3507:>                                                     (0 + 0) / 600]18/02/23 12:59:33 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result RpcResponse{requestId=8388437576763608177, body=NioManagedBuffer{buf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=81 cap=156]}} to /172.23.56.231:58822; closing connection
```

Comment: I assume you are running this in `local[*]` mode. If that's the case, you want to make sure that `driver-memory` + `executor-memory` sum up to ~60g in the case of a m4.4xlarge. From what I am seeing above, you aren't using all of  your available RAM.

Comment: I'm not using local mode. -master yarn --deploy-mode client

Comment: But, I think the issue could be due to back pressure. I think there are tons of queued kafka requests in the driver machine. Any ideas to resolve and avoid queueing the requests due to slower processing will help.

Comment: Actually the back pressure did not help. It did help in making the stream work in time, but the OOM is happening because of some other problem.

Comment: @dvshekar did you find a reason why your app was failing with OOM ? I am seeing similar behavior with spark 2.3